# Ints to be sumed left justification sum right justification

Tags: android

I want one textview to show the numbers to be sumed like:
1 3 6 = 10 the answer right justified

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gravity` attribute to do the right alignment. Set the text programmatically with `textView.setText(String text)` or in XML with `android:text="text"`

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    />
```

Comment: That will make everything right justified. The question is can I have two justifications, left for input right for answers?

Comment: You can have two TextViews, that would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

[ 1 6 7, , , ,          total    14 ]   as a new number is added to the others, the sum number reflect the total.  But the numbers must come in left to right.